# Download Android kernel source code

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I have been trying to download goldfish kernel source code but no luck.

Upon hitting the following command I end up with the source code of sized 1GB:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common
```

However we I pressed on following command,

```
git checkout -t origin/android-goldfish-2.6.29 -b goldfish
```

it prompt me:

```
Fatal error: git repository not found.
```

Even though,

```
git branch -r
```

is also giving me same error.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you just need the source, but not local git repo, then just take a snapshot that you need, i.e. [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/deprecated/android-2.6.39).
Similary you can download any git tree snapshot, just notice *tags* links over the https://android.googlesource.com

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git
```

and then

```
cd common  ==============>>> this is the step u missed.

git branch -a 

git checkout -t  remotes/origin/android-2.6.38 -b mygoldfish2_6_38 

git branch -r 

git checkout -t  origin/android-2.6.35 -b mygoldfish_2_6_35
```

and then the following command gives:

```
git branch
  android-2.6.36
  mygoldfish2_6_38
* mygoldfish_2_6_35
```