# Where can I download Android 2.6.29 kernel source code?

Tags: android, open-source, kernel

there: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm are last versions

but I need 2.6.29. Where can I download it?

Comment: if it's for a specific device, try looking at the vendor site, they _should_ make kernel source available, and most vendor do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android.git.linaro.org seems to have 2.6.29 - at least according to the list at the bottom of this page they do:

http://android.git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=kernel/common.git;a=summary

(Have a look at 'heads', http://android.git.linaro.org/git/kernel/common.git, archive/android-2.6.29)

Answer (score 0):

try this: [Download Android kernel source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178386/download-android-kernel-source-code)

Comment: http://android.git.kernel.org redirects to https://android.googlesource.com/